# How do I reset/reload/unload my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, relational-database

I have this problem while working on a problem on my assignment/homework. I wanted to load multiple data table from my SQL database into multiple datagridviews but when i click on another tab (with SelectedIndexChanged on TabControl) the column of the older loaded table still there. I just want each tab to show specific tables(columns).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace assignment2Database
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string str = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-S1O2044\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ElectroShopDB;Integrated Security=True";

private void tabSupplier_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(str);
                connection.Open();
                loadCatalogue();
            }

            else if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(str);
                connection.Open();
                loadSupplier();
            }
        }

        void loadCatalogue()
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select catalogueID,catalogueName from Catalogue";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            table.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dgvCatalogue.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(str);
            connection.Open();
            loadCatalogue();
        }

        void loadSupplier()
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select supplierID,supplierName from Supplier";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            table.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dgvSupplier.DataSource = table;
        }
```

I want the SelectedIndexChanged event when triggered on each tabs on tab control to not have the old columns of the previous datagridview appear on the new loaded datagridview. Or I just want each individual datagridview to hold a table from my SQL database.

Comment: You should create different datatable for each tab and populate respective data table and load in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Unbind the first datasource and then rebind:

```
dgvSupplier.DataSource = null;
dgvSupplier.DataSource = table;
```

This will kick out all the older columns and only populate the ones you need. Do this in every method you use to repopulate your grid:

```
    void loadCatalogue()
    {
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select catalogueID,catalogueName from Catalogue";
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        dgvSupplier.DataSource = null;
        dgvCatalogue.DataSource = table;
    }

    void loadSupplier()
    {
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select supplierID,supplierName from Supplier";
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        dgvSupplier.DataSource = null;
        dgvSupplier.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Like so.

**Edit:**

Additionally, you can create a new adapter in your population methods to empty them:

```
void loadCatalogue()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter catalogueAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select catalogueID,catalogueName from Catalogue";
            catalogueAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            table.Clear();
            catalogueAdapter.Fill(table);
            dgvSupplier.DataSource = null;
            dgvCatalogue.DataSource = table;
        }

void loadSupplier()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter supplierAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select supplierID,supplierName from Supplier";
            supplierAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            table.Clear();
            supplierAdapter.Fill(table);
            dgvSupplier.DataSource = null;
            dgvSupplier.DataSource = table;
        }
```

Comment: i did what you told but the table column still repeat. I even "= null" all 7 data tables.